Openxlsx2: Ability to create_speaklines in a group
I'm using openxlsx2 in R/Posit to create sparklines and hoping to create one group all at once. Excel allows the user to edit a group of sparklines at one time which makes it easier than editing a single spark at a time for many rows.  Does openxlsx2 allow this functionality?  I have not been able to get it to work, and might be doing something wrong.
This is the example I'm trying to replicate:
Sample
And here is the reprex code I'm trying to mimic this functionality with based on the package documentation:
sparklines <- c(create_sparklines("Sheet 1", "A2:L13", "M2:M13", markers = "1"))

t1 <- AirPassengers
t2 <- do.call(cbind, split(t1, cycle(t1)))
dimnames(t2) <- dimnames(.preformat.ts(t1))

wb <- wb_workbook()$
  add_worksheet("Sheet 1")$
  add_data(x = t2)$
  add_sparklines(sparklines = sparklines)


Not sure whether I understand you correctly, but you could use e.g. sapply (or a for loop) to create the vector of sparklines where I use rowcol_to_dims for convenience like so:
library(openxlsx2)

t1 <- AirPassengers
t2 <- do.call(cbind, split(t1, cycle(t1)))
dimnames(t2) <- dimnames(.preformat.ts(t1))

sparklines <- sapply(
  seq_len(nrow(t2)), \(row) {
    create_sparklines(
      "Sheet 1",
      rowcol_to_dims(row + 1, 1:12),
      rowcol_to_dims(row + 1, 13),
      markers = "1"
    )
  }
)

sparklines |> length()
#> [1] 12

wb <- wb_workbook()$
  add_worksheet("Sheet 1")$
  add_data(x = t2)$
  add_sparklines(sparklines = sparklines)

wb$save("foo.xlsx")



Yes, thank you for that.  However, excel allows you to specify columns in one group - so the end user who will only have access to the excel output can then edit which columns are included in the sparks, as a GROUP and not have to do each individual spark at a time.  I was hoping that openxlsx2 would also allow the group option.  My sample screenshot above will show what excel has.

You can use this:
# helper function
sparkline_group <- function(sparklines) {
  slg <- sparklines[1]
  sl <- xml_node(sparklines[-1], "x14:sparklineGroup", "x14:sparklines", "x14:sparkline")
  xml_add_child(slg, sl, level = c("x14:sparklines"))
}

In @stefan's example
library(openxlsx2)

t1 <- AirPassengers
t2 <- do.call(cbind, split(t1, cycle(t1)))
dimnames(t2) <- dimnames(.preformat.ts(t1))

sparklines <- sapply(
  seq_len(nrow(t2)), \(row) {
    create_sparklines(
      "Sheet 1",
      rowcol_to_dims(row + 1, 1:12),
      rowcol_to_dims(row + 1, 13),
      markers = "1"
    )
  }
)

sparklines_grp <- sparkline_group(sparklines)

sparklines_grp |> length()
#> [1] 1

wb <- wb_workbook()$
  add_worksheet("Sheet 1")$
  add_data(x = t2)$
  add_sparklines(sparklines = sparklines_grp)

if (interactive()) wb$open()



Nice, Jan. Will keep this approach to manipulate the xml code in mind. BTW: Just out of curiosity I prepared a draft for a PR which allows to add multiple sparklines as a group using the OPs code. See here.

:) If it works and passes our tests (and maybe a new one), this will be a very welcome addition. (Honestly, I hadn't heard of the whole feature until I saw this post yesterday).

Great, Jan. Will do. It works and (after a small change) passes all tests. Of course will I add a new test.
